# How to round each item in a list of floats to 2 decimal places?

Tags: python

I have a list which consists of float values but they're too detailed to proceed. I know we can shorten them by using the `("%.f" % variable)` operator, like:

```
result = [359.70000000000005]
result = "%.2f" % result
result = [359.70]
```

My question is how can I turn a list of values into their rounded equivalents without using an iterator. I've tried something, but it throws a `TypeError`:

```
list = [0.30000000000000004, 0.5, 0.20000000000000001]
list = "%.2f" % list
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

How can I provide a clean list like:

```
list = [0.30, 0.5, 0.20]
```

Comment: Serious confusion of concepts here.  For example `0.2` and `0.20000000000000001` are representations of the *same* double precision floating point number.  Just start your interpreter and enter `0.2` to see this.

Comment: @SvenMarnach My 3.11.3 interpreter outputs `0.2`, So I guess Python has updated its float representations.

Comment: @Wilson [Indeed they did](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/45921). And it actually happened before I wrote the comment above, but it was only available in Python 3.x, which nobody was using at the time. The change was later backported to Python 2.7.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

`"%.2f"` does not return a *clean* float. It returns a **string** representing this float with two decimals.

```
my_list = [0.30000000000000004, 0.5, 0.20000000000000001]
my_formatted_list = [ '%.2f' % elem for elem in my_list ]
```

returns:

```
['0.30', '0.50', '0.20']
```

Also, don't call your variable `list`. This is a reserved word for list creation. Use some other name, for example `my_list`.

If you want to obtain `[0.30, 0.5, 0.20]` (or at least the floats that are the closest possible), you can try this:

```
my_rounded_list = [ round(elem, 2) for elem in my_list ]
```

returns:

```
[0.29999999999999999, 0.5, 0.20000000000000001]
```

Comment: Thanks, eumiro. Just used "list" for explanation.

Comment: Even better than `myList` would be `my_list` to comply with PEP 8.

Comment: "If you want to obtain [0.30, 0.5, 0.20], try this: myRoundedList = [ round(elem, 2) for elem in myList ]   returns [0.29999999999999999, 0.5, 0.20000000000000001]". So this code does not obtain what he wants to obtain (which you made clear also [0.30, 0.5, 0.20], two decimal points floats only).

Comment: @Darksky - There is no **float** `0.20` in Python. The closest one is  `0.20000000000000001`. But there is its decimal representation with two decimals `"0.20"`.

Answer (score 69):

If you really want an iterator-free solution, you can use numpy and its [array round](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.around.html) function.

```
import numpy as np
myList = list(np.around(np.array(myList),2))
```

Comment: This. This solution should go up, and the rest down.

Comment: Works for my use-case. Thanks ever so much :D

Comment: It looks like `around()` returns an `ndarray`. The `list()` call from the answer fixes that.

Answer (score 12):

You might want to look at Python's [`decimal`](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html#module-decimal) module, which can make using floating point numbers and doing arithmetic with them a lot more intuitive. Here's a trivial example of one way of using it to "clean up" your list values:

```
>>> from decimal import *
>>> mylist = [0.30000000000000004, 0.5, 0.20000000000000001]
>>> getcontext().prec = 2
>>> ["%.2f" % e for e in mylist]
['0.30', '0.50', '0.20']
>>> [Decimal("%.2f" % e) for e in mylist]
[Decimal('0.30'), Decimal('0.50'), Decimal('0.20')]
>>> data = [float(Decimal("%.2f" % e)) for e in mylist]
>>> data
[0.3, 0.5, 0.2]
```

Answer (score 12):

```
mylist = [0.30000000000000004, 0.5, 0.20000000000000001]
myRoundedList =  [round(x,2) for x in mylist] 
# [0.3, 0.5, 0.2]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the built-in [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) along with a [`lambda` expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
my_list = [0.2111111111, 0.5, 0.3777777777]
my_list_rounded = list(map(lambda x: round(x, ndigits=2), my_list))
my_list_rounded                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Out[3]: [0.21, 0.5, 0.38]
```

Alternatively you could also create a named function for the rounding up to a specific digit using [`partial`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functools.html#functools.partial) from the *[functools](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functools.html#module-functools) module for working with higher order functions*:

```
from functools import partial

my_list = [0.2111111111, 0.5, 0.3777777777]
round_2digits = partial(round, ndigits=2)
my_list_rounded = list(map(round_2digits, my_list))
my_list_rounded                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Out[6]: [0.21, 0.5, 0.38]
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option which doesn't require numpy is:

```
precision = 2  
myRoundedList = [int(elem*(10**precision)+delta)/(10.0**precision) for elem in myList]

# delta=0 for floor
# delta = 0.5 for round
# delta = 1 for ceil
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way in Python 3 is to use `numpy.round()` to make a rounded array, and `list()` to turn it back into a list. There is no need to make the list into an array before sending it to `numpy.round()`

```py
import numpy as np

my_list = [0.342514, 0.52341234, 0.21234354346]

rounded_list = list(np.round(my_list, 2))
```

Output: `[0.34, 0.52, 0.21]`

If you don't want to have numpy as a dependency, then eumiro's iterator solution is the best option.

Answer (score 1):

I came to this stackoverflow page looking for a function to round a list of 2D coordinates. Here are two ways to do that similar to the answer provided by [Wilson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13721819/wilson) using numpy. Notice that the first way coerces all values to floats and the second maintains the integers found in the original list.

```
pts = [[9, 0], [8.072989510489503, 2.768356643356639], [-0.18750000000001532, 3.1761363636363544]]
pts_rounded_arr = np.round(pts, 2)
pts_rounded_lstof_arr = [np.round(p, 2) for p in pts]
pts_rounded_lst1 = np.round(pts, 2).tolist()
pts_rounded_lst2 = [np.round(p, 2).tolist() for p in pts]

print(f"{pts=}")
print(f"pts_rounded_arr=\n{pts_rounded_arr}")
print(f"{pts_rounded_lstof_arr=}")
print(f"{pts_rounded_lst1=}")
print(f"{pts_rounded_lst2=}")
```

Output:

```
pts=[[9, 0], [8.072989510489503, 2.768356643356639], [-0.18750000000001532, 3.1761363636363544]]
pts_rounded_arr=

    [[ 9.     0. ]
    [ 8.07  2.77]
    [-0.19  3.18]]
pts_rounded_lstof_arr=[array([9, 0]), array([8.07, 2.77]), array([-0.19,  3.18])]
pts_rounded_lst1=[[9.0, 0.0], [8.07, 2.77], [-0.19, 3.18]]
pts_rounded_lst2=[[9, 0], [8.07, 2.77], [-0.19, 3.18]]
```

Comment: Looks good for me. Why not change to "2" to match the question.

Comment: Good point. I updated the answer to round to 2 decimal places to better match the original question.

Comment: `pts_rounded_arr.tolist()` returns `pts_rounded_lst`, no? Why bother with the list comprehension?

Comment: Thanks, I updated the answer to illustrate the subtle difference. Basically the comprehension method maintains any integer values from the original list, whereas `np.round(pts, 2).tolist()` coerces all values to floating point.

Answer (score 0):

**Easiest way :**

import numpy as np

np.round(list,2)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).